# .net spitting out different date format between localhost and azure website

Tags: c#, .net, azure, model-view-controller

I have an issue where when I run my web app from VS2013 it gives me one date format and when I address it deployed on Azure it gives me a completely different date format.

Here is an example:
top: running on Azure; bottom: running locally from VS
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGiZQ.jpg
[image]

This happens when using Canadian (en-CA) culture in the browser.

Before appearing on the UI, they are delivered as strings into custom element attributes together with all the other data, then parsed by jquery.

The relevant code in the model looks like this:

```
dynamic dynEffectiveStartDate
if (blah blah) 
{
     dynEffectiveStartDate = object.EffectiveStartDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
else
{
     dynEffectiveStartDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
var dataStruct = new
{
     StartDate = dynEffectiveStartDate,
     EndDate = dynEffectiveEndDate,
     SomeStuff = anotherImportantDataString,
     DataStore = someMoreImportantData
};
…
someObject.serializedData = javascriptserializer.Serialize(dataStruct);
…
```

Later I use *$.datepicker.parsedate("mm/dd/yy", value)* in the UI to deliver the current value to the appropriate editor, but it collapses because there are dashes instead of slashes. Normally I would use *$.datepicker.setDefault($.datepicer.regional[cultureVariable]);* to format dates in the UI for the user and then use ("getDate") and *$.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yyyy")* when recording it back into a custom attribute before post.

So even when browser shows 31/12/2014 for Englishmen or Australians, I still post 12/31/2014 back to my controller.

en-CA culture code, however, does one thing locally and a different thing remotely. So far as I know, *DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");* returns format "MM-dd-yyyy", which is vexing, because I need to parse it into a real date later on. There's no knowing whether it will start spitting out "dd-mm-yyyy" or "yyyy/mm/dd" if someone in China or wherever else uses the application.

How can I make sure that the back end delivers the date format I tell it to?

Comment: are you sure that culture in the browser is causing this change? i think the date format will be same once you deploy it to azure and will not depend upon where you access it from / culture of the brower

Comment: Hello, Parv, I should have put this picture in as well: http://i.stack.imgur.com/h2Hid.jpg
This is the same page on Azure under "en-GB" culture. Note the date is in mm/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: Mandatory XKCD link - http://xkcd.com/1179/ - use ISO 8601 and live happily thereafter... Or at least use `("o")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are multiple problems here which i can think of
1. `DateTime.Now` - this will give you different results depending upon where you deploy it to. To overcome this problem save the timezone in some resource file OR static settings inside your code and then use `DateTime.UtcNow.Add(*/the time zone difference*/)`
2. You should be using the overload of DateTime.ToString(string, culture) [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64(v=vs.110).aspx). This will keep your format same no matter what the culture is because now you are responsible for providing the culture. So now your code should look like `.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`
3. Using a culture dependent format to send the data to the UI in json. [read this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5075/Culture-Invariant-DateTime-values)
4. Sending culture dependent datetime to the UI. Just a suggestion what i do in my projects is that i send UTC time([ISO 8601](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#Roundtrip)) to the UI where in js code it is easier to parse it and then change it according to the timezone of the browser. Without this i will have to guess the timezone of the user using the location from the IP address(totally not worth the effort). this you can do easily using only vanila js OR you can use some of the js library(one that i use is [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/))

Comment: Thank you, the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture worked nicely. Honestly I would not even bother about culture now, since I have no respect whatsoever for anything except ISO, but I inherited this code and need a quick fix now before I can go on a full-out bug hunt in the next sprint.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using culture variants, you could force it like this

```
string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Year);
```